# Ansible version difference in AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I have same ansible version, in a virtual machine and Ansible AWX virtual env which is Ansible 2.11. But when I run the playbook on Ansible AWX, I get errors tried to replicate in virtual machine what might be source of it, and found it's same error as If I have Ansible 2.9 in AWX.

How could this possible? is there a way to verify Ansible AWX version running beyond using debug mode on AWX?
I verified virtual env in AWX and it's setup with Ansible 2.11 and same modules used in virtual machine. So no clear idea why I get Ansible 2.9 errors in 2.11 environment. Can the ansible runner be a cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to verify Ansible AWX version running beyond using debug mode on AWX?

You could run the following playbook in AWX:

```
- shell: ansible -—version
  register: ansible_v
  delegate_to: localhost 

- debug:
    msg: “{{ ansible_v }}”
```